# how to create an input with increment and decrement buttons in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to create an input with increment and decrement buttons in react native
here is an example of what I need:

[image: input with spinner]

I am new to react native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made one here: [snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/@mateensr/handlecounter)

You have to have such knowledge of React Native to be able to customize it down to your needs. You must have to read react native docs and may need to google things to set up a custom component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => setCount(count - 1)}
      style={{ height: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 20, alignItems: 'center' }}
      >
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>-</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TextInput style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black',  height: 20}}
      value={`${count}`}
      onChangeText={() => {}}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)}
        style={{ height: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 20, alignItems: 'center' }}
      >
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>+</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    number: 0
  };

  onIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 });
  };
  onDecrement = () => {
    this.setState({ number: this.state.number - 1 });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Counter
        <button onClick={this.onDecrement}>-</button>
        <input value={this.state.number} />
        <button onClick={this.onIncrement}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```